# matrix differentation

Tags: matrix-calculus

I want to find the derivative of the $f:X→(X′X)^{-1}$ where $X$ is a $m×n$ matrix.

Now I know that the differential of $d(X^{−1})=−X^{−1}(dX)X^{−1}$. Can I use this directly to get the differential for the function I want to differentiate above?

Any derivations of this differential and derivative would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the matrix for the given linear transformation on Euclidean space is nonsingular, I don't see why not. Some clear and detailed discussions can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190424/how-to-evaluate-the-derivatives-of-matrix-inverse). I particularly recommend Richard Schoonhoven's wonderful response,I think you'll find it exactly what you're looking for.

Hey,why waste a perfectly good answer someone worked hard posting?

Comment: what is meant with nonsingular?

Comment: Nonsingular means for a matrix A,$det(A)\neq 0$. It's proven in linear algebra this is equivalent to saying A is invertible.