# Derivative of a function expressed in terms of matrix products

Tags: real-analysis

Let

$$
f(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix}
   h_{1}(x, y) & h_{2}(x, y)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   h_{1,1}(x, y) & h_{1,2}(x, y) \\
   h_{2,1}(x, y) & h_{2,2}(x, y)
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
   k_{1} \\
   k_{2}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I want to  calculate its partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.  The problem I have concerns the derivative of the inverse matrix. How can I do that?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190424/how-to-evaluate-the-derivatives-of-matrix-inverse

Comment: IMHO, it is not worth the value to stay with matrix notations in such a low dimensional case : your function is nothing else than : $\dfrac{k_1(h_1h_{22}-h_2h_{21})+k_2(h_2h_{11}-h_1h_{22})}{D}$ where $D:=h_{11}h_{22}-h_{21}h_{12}$